# Running schtasks through PHP script

Tags: php, windows-task-scheduler

I want to run this command in my script

```
passthru("Schtasks.exe /create /SC WEEKLY /D MON /TN \"helloworld\" /TR \"C:/wamp64/www/stage/jobs/AddSomeRecords_0.1\" /ST 03:00",$return_value);
```

The same code works perfectly when I try it directly in cmd but it does nothing through the script. I have passed couple of days searching and all I found is "The IIS anonymous user needs permissions on schtasks.exe!". unfortunately, I could not succeed in doing this. I am using windows10. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please add the actual php command you execute to the question. There is an `edit` link below the question. Use it.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that, i did it now

Comment: Are you sure that the user that executes the command has the appropriate permissions?

Comment: How to add these permissions ?